# Setjmp/longjmp in Ruby’s Continuation

Tags: c, ruby, continuations, setjmp

I was wondering about this while digging through the code of `cont.c` in Ruby’s current version. The documentation of `setjmp` says that calling `longjmp` on the jmp_buf structure *after* the caller of `setjmp` returned is an error. But, it seems that Ruby does this happily and does not crash:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/05f087c844f0e1e7cfe323edcf591de64069a289/cont.c#L522
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/05f087c844f0e1e7cfe323edcf591de64069a289/cont.c#L775
(+ a couple more usages with fibers)

And I ask: how is that possible?

I did notice that the same source code uses also `set/getcontext`, but only with fibers or so it seems. It would seem more reasonable to me to use these functions rather than `set/longjmp`.

Comment: Undefined behavior, but it usually works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, but those examples call `ruby_setjmp()`, not `setjmp()`.  Is the former a wrapper around the latter?  If so, is it possible that it has instrumentation to make this work (e.g. creating a duplicate stack frame, or performing some other magic to allow a corresponding (`ruby_`)`longjmp()` to work)?

Comment: @cremno ok, I expected something like that. But it’s not very reassuring, to be honest.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is basically an alias: 
`#define ruby_setjmp(env) RUBY_SETJMP(env)`
`#define RUBY_SETJMP(env) _setjmp(env)`
And almost the same for ruby_longjmp.

Comment: It's not that simple, since CRuby can use `__builtin_setjmp()`, `_setjmp()`, `sigsetjmp()`, `setjmp()`, or `setjmpex()` as `RUBY_SETJMP()`. Likely all of those variations also don't define this. Actually if you look above the ` ruby_longjmp()` call there seems to be some code related to the stack context.