# Correlating dtrace probes

Tags: ruby, macos, dtrace

I'm seeing unexpected results using dtrace, in that my `-entry` and `-return` results don't always seem to correlate, I seem to see either too many or too few, and have simplified my script to explore what is going wrong.

I'm attempting to profile the amount of time spent in `require "./foo"`s in my Ruby code using the following D script:

```
ruby*:::require-entry
{
  self->start = timestamp;
  @counts["require-entry"] = count();
}

ruby*:::require-return
/self->start/
{
  @counts["correlated require returns"] = count();
  self->start = 0;
}

ruby*:::require-return
/!self->start/
{
  /* @reqTimes[copyinstr(arg0)] = quantize(self->start - timestamp); */
  @counts["uncorrelated require returns"] = count();
}
```

Running this prints:

```
$ time sudo dtrace -q -s script.d -c './script.rb'

  correlated require returns                                     5691
  uncorrelated require returns                                   7872
  require-entry                                                  7877
sudo dtrace -q -s script.d -c './script.rb'  0.22s user 0.22s system 3% cpu 13.488 total
```

- am I using the `self->` variables correctly (vs. `this->` or similar?)
- are my predicates correct?
- when running dtrace this way, do I "race" against the probes activating before the script starts?

Comment: Ruby badly abuses `setjmp()`/`longjmp()`- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569337/setjmp-longjmp-in-ruby-s-continuation. Is there any possibility that Ruby is jumping into/out of the calls you're trying to trace?

Answer (score 0):

> am I using the self-> variables correctly

Probably not. Because the third clause will always run (`self->start=0`). That’s the problem.

If you have recent enough (`dtrace -V` ≥ `dtrace: Sun D 1.14`) dtrace version, you can do

```
ruby*:::require-return
{
  if (self->start)
    @counts["correlated require returns"] = count();
  else
    @counts["uncorrelated require returns"] = count();

  self->start = 0;
}
```

otherwise

```
ruby*:::require-return
{
  @counts[self->start ? "correlated require returns" : "uncorrelated require returns"] = count();
  self->start = 0;
}
```

will do the trick too.

Comment: thanks, I'll go do some more digging and see what I can turn up - I haven't touched this project in a while and will need to refresh my memory.